# Tensor must be from the same graph as Tensor in LinearClassifier with AdagradDA Optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have been trying to use tf.optimizer.AdagradDA with a Linear Classifier. Here is my code:

```
def input_fn():
    features_in = { "random_var": tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(100)) }
    labels_in = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100,), p=[1./2, 1./2]))
    dataset =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((features_in, labels_in))
    dataset.repeat(2)
    dataset.batch(1)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return features, labels

def main():
    global_step_tensor = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradDAOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, global_step=global_step_tensor)
    columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('random_var')]
    model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(optimizer=optimizer, feature_columns=columns)
    model.train(input_fn=input_fn)
```

When I'm running the code I'm getting one of the following errors:

- `ValueError: Tensor("Identity_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("linear/linear_model/random_var/weights/part_0:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32_ref).`
- `ValueError: Tensor("Identity_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("linear/head/AdagradDA/update_linear/linear_model/random_var/weights/part_0/Cast_2/x:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`
- `ValueError: Tensor("Identity_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("linear/linear/linear_model/random_var/weights/part_0/AdagradDA_1:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32_ref).`

When I run the same code with a **FtrlOptimizer** or a **AdagradOptimize** the code runs properly. So I'm guessing, the issue has to be related with the `global_step_tensor` instanciation.

---

Here are the things that I have tried so far:

- Move the code snippet into a `with tf.Session() as sess:`
- Creating the optimizer into the `LinearClassifier` constructor

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: This works in TensorFlow 1.10.0 (and possible later). Apparently it does not work in TensorFlow 1.9.0 (and possibly earlier). See comment below by ZakJ.

You need to change the way you construct your optimizer object as follows:

```
optimizer = lambda: tf.train.AdagradDAOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001,global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

1) Notice the lambda. This will create a callable, as opposed to a Tensorflow `operation`, which is what `AdagradDAOptimizer` would return on its own (without the lambda).

2) You can use `tf.train.get_global_step()` directly and don't have to define a global step tensor.

I'm not quite sure why you need to create a callable by adding the lambda in this case. But I guess whenever you want to use an optimizer that needs `global_step` (or you want to pass it, for example for learning rate decay) you need to set the optimizer to a callable (hence the need for lambda) instead of a Tensorflow `operation`.

This is also what the learning rate decay example does in the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNLinearCombinedRegressor).

This is the complete code I successfully ran on TensorFlow 1.10.0:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def input_fn():
    features_in = { "random_var": tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(100)) }
    labels_in = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100,), p=[1./2, 1./2]))
    dataset =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((features_in, labels_in))
    dataset.repeat(2)
    dataset.batch(1)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return features, labels

def main():
    optimizer = lambda: tf.train.AdagradDAOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001,global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('random_var')]
    model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(optimizer=optimizer, feature_columns=columns)
    model.train(input_fn=input_fn)
```

Comment: At least in version 1.9.0, this does not work.  You receive an error like: `The given object is not an Optimizer instance. Given: <function <lambda> at 0x7fc4c043a0c8>`.

Comment: I updated the answer with the complete code that works on Tensorflow 1.10.0 for me. Can you try this exact code on 1.9.0 and let me know if you still get that error?

Comment: I used this exact code, with the addition that I returned `model` from main and then added:   `est = main();  est.fit(input_fn)`.  This call to `fit` gave the same error as I gave above.

Comment: Did you mean `est.train(input_fn)`? the `LinearClassifier` object does not have a fit() method. But when I do what you described with `est.train(input_fn)`, the code runs fine. Again, this is 1.10.0 though. Thanks for trying it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I meant ".train" -- sorry, I can't edit the comment to correct it.  It sounds like something was added in 1.10.0 that allows this.  You're right that the modern documentation gives similar solutions.  Removing the down-vote since you've added the caveat of version to the answer.